# Tera Data: Missing/Invalid SQL statement'E(3810)

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-merge

I have this simple merge statement but it failed when running.
Any advice is appreciated.

```
MERGE INTO HP.SampleAll as A 
USING ( 
        select ALIGNED
        from HP.Sample2
       ) as B
ON (A.md_nbr = B.md_nbr)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET ALIGNED = A.ALIGNED ;
```

Comment: "Failed"? Error message? There's no `B.md_nbr` selcted.

Comment: Please post your exact error message.  Also, your `SET ALIGNED = A.ALIGNED` statement doesn't look right.  The way you have it now, it doesn't look like you're setting a new value.  Do you mean to have `SET A.ALIGNED = B.ALIGNED`?

Comment: Missing/Invalid SQL statement'E(3810)

Comment: According to the syntax...that's how you assign values for a merge statement

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET ALIGNED = A.ALIGNED 

I have tried several ways but none work so far

Answer (score 0):

Error 3810 says that Column does not exist.

md_nbr dont exist in your subquery B - as you don't select it.

Maybe a solution is:

```
MERGE INTO HP.SampleAll as A 
USING ( 
        select ALIGNED, md_nbr
        from HP.Sample2
       ) as B
ON (A.md_nbr = B.md_nbr)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
 SET ALIGNED = A.ALIGNED ;
```

or just `USING HP.Sample2 as B`